# What is the difference between ‘mapleader’ and ‘g:mapleader’ in Vim?

Tags: global-variables, vim

I don’t understand the difference between `let mapleader=","` and `let g:mapleader=","`. I know that `g:` means that it’s a global variable, but I don’t clearly understand the difference. Which one should I use in my `.vimrc` file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the aforementioned statements are both located outside of function
definitions, they have the identical effect of setting a global variable.
However, if the first statement (without the `g:` prefix) is used in
a function body, it defines a variable *local* to that function. See
`:help internal-variables` and especially `:helpg In a function:`.

Hence, outside function definitions one can access the global map-leader
variable simply as `mapleader`.

Answer (score 3):

```
let mapleader=","
```

as stated in the doc.

Why would you want to use `g:mapleader`? `g:` is mostly used in plugins to `let` global variables in order to expose settings to other plugins or for you to play with in your .vimrc.

Comment: One would use `g:mapleader` to access the map leader global variable in a function.  See relevant references to the Vim help in my answer.

Comment: Yes, but not in what I believe is the question's context: setting `mapleader` to `,`.

Comment: Setting `mapleader` could occur in a function.  Especially if you consider that the value of `mapleader` is used for the `<leader>` at the moment the mapping is defined.